# how do you paste strings using for loop?

Tags: python

I would like to iterate through a list of items pasting the same item into a larger string using python3

This is what I have thus far:

```
file_list = ['car', 'bike', 'bus']

for file in file_list: 
    print("taking a %s is better than other options because %s's let you get around the city faster" %(file))
```

I end up with a TypeError: not enough arguments for format string.

What I would like to end up with is three separate statements as strings.

1. taking a **car** is better than other options because **car**'s let you get around the city faster
2. taking a **bike** is better than other options because **bike**'s let you get around the city faster
3. taking a **bus** is better than other options because **bus**'s let you get around the city faster

Comment: i would call *car*, *bike* and *bus* `vehicles` rather than `files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format` (new-style formatting) with numbered palceholders:

```
for file in file_list: 
    print("taking a {0} is better than other options because \
           {0}'s let you get around the city faster".format(file))
```

`0` here refers to the first argument passed to `str.format`, which is the sole argument here.

Comment: You can do something similar with `%`, using a `dict`, but it's verbose: `'%(f)s %(f)s' % {'f': file}`. (Or use `locals()` as the dict and use the variable name itself as the key in the format string.)

Comment: @chepner Ok...amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting:

```
file_list = ['car', 'bike', 'bus']
for i, a in enumerate(file_list, 1):
   print("{n}. taking a {vehicle} is better than other options because {vehicle}'s let you get around the city faster".format(n=i, vehicle=a))
```

Output:

```
1. taking a car is better than other options because car's let you get around the city faster
2. taking a bike is better than other options because bike's let you get around the city faster
3. taking a bus is better than other options because bus's let you get around the city faster
```

Comment: `enumerate` can start the numbering at 1: `enumerate(file_list, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

*simple thing you were missing*

i guess you have learnt where you were wrong

```
file_list = ['car', 'bike', 'bus']

for file in file_list: 
    print("taking a %s is better than other options because %s's let you get around the city faster" %(file,file))
```